# good practice to populate data in to elasticsearch from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, message-queue

i have read some documentations and found some interesting ways to implement the realtime sync with elasticsearch to populate data.

1. logstash with (input plugins (mysql-- running every 5 seconds))
2. logstash with( input plugins (sqs, kafka, rabbitMQ))
3. using message queus only(rabbitMQ..)
4. add it in api level only(in the transaction with (mysql or other dbs))

which one will be a fault-tolerent method and give near realtime perfomance benefits?

My requrement will be to populate 3 Tables from mysql to elasticsearch(have many to many relationship  need to denormalize and save) and sync 1:1 with elasticsearch while perfoming **CURD** operations

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write your data in a Kafka topic and after with a consumer app or logstash to write your data to ElasticSearch:

1. Kafka is a high available and high scalable message queue and storage.
2. If our logstash crash(**logstash with (input plugins (mysql-- running every 5 seconds))**) you must restart manualy this service.
3. If a consumer if failed and you have multiple instances of that consumer, the other two will take over the load.
4. If Elastic Search is unavailable for some time(this happen to me) you will lose date